# BHO Plugin not working properly

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I have implement BHO Plugin to detect NUmber from webpage using C#.Every time page loaded append javascript in webpage and that javascript detect number and replaced it with hyperlink number.

**Code**

```
 public void  WebBrowser_DownloadComplete()
{
HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;

    IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)
                           document.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);
    IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject = 
      (IHTMLScriptElement)document.createElement("script");
    scriptObject.type = @"text/javascript";
    scriptObject.src = @"myscript.js";
((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject);


}
```

**Problems**

When I test Plugin with offline web pages it is working Fine. But with online pages it is not working. DownloadComplete event triggers multiple time.

**Questions**

Which event is triggered by IE when page is refresh and loaded?

Answer (score 4):

You have to add condition in `DocumentLoaded` event like below,

```
if (rootDocLoaded && (HTMLDocument != null) && url != "about:blank"){
  //Your code here
}
```

Using above condition its called only one after full page loaded. And you can also use `beforeNavigate` and `Navigate` method also.